# Call a php file from an action in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a requirement.In my `indexAction()` I want to call a php file e.g. `verify.php`. How can I do this? Do I need any changes in my `application.ini` file.

Please respond immediately.Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP files are not callable. Probably you should add some code how you normally *"call"* php files so it's more clear what you're asking.

Comment: @hakre it is possible to return variables from includes, not sure if this is what the OP is referring to

Comment: Yeah, it's totally unclear what's asked here. Probably call means include, but who knows?

Comment: here call means I have to redirect.Foe example I have a url in browser http://localhost:8080/index now this url will call indexAction() Now in indexAction I have to redirect to verify.php(for example) now the url would be http://localhost:8080/mst/verify.php as verify.php is in 'mst' folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your action:

`$this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrlAndExit('/mst/verify.php');`

Answer (score 1):

If your file exist e.g. '/mst/verify.php' then you have to do as @David Weinraub said.
But if it is virtual - you have to write own router in a bootstrap file for example and do as @David Weinraub said again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should make a model, in the index method you make an instance of that object and call a defined method...